# Encryption and Decryption of string with out using Base64String

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to encrypt Decrypt text without using Base64String?

I don't want to use Base64String because encrypted text should not contains any special character like @, $, #, /, \, |,=,% ,^

Comment: Note that Base64 is normally called "encoding", not encryption.

Comment: _I want a code sample_ This is not a good way to ask a question on Stackoverflow. This place is for specific programming problems. Just do some effort..

Comment: _encrypted text should not contains any special character_  - no real encryption method will satisfy that. Look for ROT13.

Answer (score 4):

Well the obvious approach if you don't want to use base64 is to use base16 - i.e. hex.

There are plenty of examples of converting between a byte array and a hex string representation on Stack Overflow. (`BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "")` is an inefficient way of performing the conversion to a string; there's nothing *quite* as simple for the reverse, but it's not much code.)

EDIT: As noted in comments, [`SoapHexBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has a simple way of doing this. You may wish to wrap the use of that class in a less SOAP-specific type, of course :)

Of course that will use rather more space than base64. One alternative is to use base64, but using a different set of characters: find 65 characters you *can* use (the 65th is for padding) and encode it that way. (You may find there's a base64 library available which allows you to specify the characters to use, but if not it's pretty easy to write.)

Do *not* try to just use a normal `Encoding` - it's not appropriate for data which isn't fundamentally text.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you can use [base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) as well. That can be case-insensitive (potentially handy) and you can avoid I/1 and O/0 for added clarity. It's harder to code and debug though.

Comment: +1. Nice and blazingly fast answer :). I like Base32 more than Base16 as it a bit more compact and still safe for upper/lower case conversion (and much more interesting to write too).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I'll add it as an option, but generally "interesting" scares me ;)

Comment: For base 16 and back again I find [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to work best. `new SoapHexBinary(myByteArray).ToString()` gets you the hex and `SoapHexBinary.Parse(myString).Value` gets you the `byte[]` back again.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Nice find, and I'll link it in the answer - but I'm always wary of using a type which is clearly related to one specific purpose (SOAP) when doing something entirely different. I wish the core of that had been put into somewhere in `System`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great example in the MySQL Connector source code for the ASP.NET membership provider implementation. It may be a little hassle to download and research, but it has a well-established encryption and decryption module in there.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloads
Choose the 'source code' option before downloading.

If you want encoding/decoding for data transmission or condensed character storage, you should edit your question.  Answers given to an encoding question will be much different than answers given to an encryption/decryption question.